# 'Map to network resource' doesn't work after upgrade to Chrome 49

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I just updated to Chrome 49 and 'Map to network resource' feature doesn't work anymore. I can right click it, it just doesn't do anything. Anyone is having the same problem for version 49 (49.0.2623.87 m (64-bit))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug since Chrome 49 because network resources are mapped with the prefix "file:///", so chrome does not have permissions to write.